# BLE Scan Request used for signaling to an iBeacon?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Is it possible to send a signal to an iBeacon in the form of a scan request to let the beacon know their advertising packet was heard?

This way we could turn on an LED whenever the beacon detects that some other device heard it.

Comment: That's not the normal "mode of iBeacon". They should only advertise, whereas someone or no-one listens to them. There exist a dual mode version that can listen. After all, it's just a specificity of BLE items.

Comment: Yes I know it is not normal mode to activate an LED. However I'm wondering if it is possible. Anyway if you have more info on this dual mode version let me know. Often when searching for 'dual mode ble' you find stuff that has modes for both BLE and non-low energy bluetooth. Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

**Bluetooth LE advertisements, including beacon advertisements are one way.  There is no standard mechanism to acknowledge receipt.**

The typical alternative to do what you want is to actually connect to the beacon using a GATT Service. This can let it know you heard the advertisement.  The disadvantage is that connections stop advertising, so you need to make it short lived.

Another alternative is to make the beacon also scan for other advertisements around it.  You could then echo the same advertisement back to it (with a change in the beacon type bytes to differentiate it) but because advertisement delivery is not guaranteed, you would certainly need to send the response back many times to maki it reliable.

None of these solution s are standard. All would require a custom beacon.

Comment: Absolutely I'm talking about a custom beacon. I want to program a BLE device that acts like an iBeacon and can also (in the easiest way possible) know when it's advertisement was heard. So I don't care about standard mechanisms unless the ble chips impose limitations that are difficult to get around. So yes, iBeacon mode would start advertising, then we could connect (non-standard for iBeacons) write some characteristic and then disconnect. Alternatively I was wondering if scan request and scan response could be used as a way to signal. That seems like 2 way to me. Why can that not be used?